# Create Jquery array from ajax response

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to add or remove classes to some divs.
These divs should be assigned different classes depending on the value of their html.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my code isn't working.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'loc/bcheck.php',
    success: function(data){
        tArrx = new Array(data);
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('.bHr').each(function(){
            curElm = $(this);
            var bTm = curElm.html();
            if ($.inArray(bTm, tArrx) !== -1){
                curElm.addClass('disabled');
                curElm.removeClass('available');
            }
            else{
                curElm.addClass('available');
                curElm.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});

<div class="bHr">1</div>
<div class="bHr">5</div>
```

All values of the divs' html are caught correctly.
And the function runs without errors.
But I allways get the same result, value is not present in array.

'data' is **1", "2", "3", "4** and using console.log it returns **["1", "2", "3", "4"]**

Comment: where you get bTm? i think it should be Tbm

Comment: `var bTm = curElm.html().trim();`

Comment: try to set `dataType: 'json'` for the ajax request then `tArrx = data;`...

Comment: If I define tArrx manually the function works fine, without having to add '.trim()'. The problem appears when I create the array using 'data'. The content of 'data' is written in the question, 1", "2", "3", "4

Comment: So what does the console log show for tArrx? does it show ["1", "2", "3", "4"] just like data?

Comment: 'data' is 1", "2", "3", "4 and using console.log it returns ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

Comment: but what is tArrx? Is it showing the same as data in the console log or an alert or whatever?

Comment: data is the response of a PHP file and it's value is   1","2","3","4
If I use 'console.log(tArrx)' I get    ["1","2","3","4"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. The problem was that the PHP response was not an PHP array. To fix this I made my response an array and added this to my PHP file:

```
json_encode($tArrx);
```

And changed my jQuery as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'loc/bcheck.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        tArrx = data;
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('.bHr').each(function(){
            curElm = $(this);
            var bTm = curElm.html();
            if ($.inArray(bTm, tArrx) !== -1){
                curElm.addClass('disabled');
                curElm.removeClass('available');
            }
            else{
                curElm.addClass('available');
                curElm.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I used the examples from all of you guys to achieve this and I thank you for it. Couldn't have done it without your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `new Array(data)`, if data is of string type then it creates an array with one element which is the string, else if data is an array then the `tArrx` will be an array with 1 element which is the array so your `$.inArray()` will always return `-1`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'loc/bcheck.php',
    //set datatype as json
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var tArrx = data;
        $('.bHr').each(function () {
            var curElm = $(this);
            //wrong variable name& you might have to trim the html contents
            var bTm = curElm.html().trim();
            if ($.inArray(bTm, tArrx) !== -1) {
                curElm.addClass('disabled');
                curElm.removeClass('available');
            } else {
                curElm.addClass('available');
                curElm.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I just get 'tArrx is not defined' now.

Comment: @user1885099 remove the `var` infront of `var tArrx = data;`, I think you are using it else where also

Comment: Ok, if I use the .each function inside the 'success' it dosn't do anything when the value is in the array (no error, just nothing). If I use the .each function in 'complete' I get the 'tArrx is not defined' error even though I tried removing 'var' from 'tArrx'.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually created a multidimensional array

```
tArrx = new Array(data);
```

So this is how you would match your array

```
var data = ["1","2","3","4"];
var tArrx = new Array(data);
confirm(tArrx[0]);
confirm(data);
confirm($.inArray('1', tArrx[0]) !== -1);
```

Better yet simply don't cast data to an array

```
var data = ["1","2","3","4"];
confirm(data);
confirm($.inArray('1', data) !== -1);
```

[Working example HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/threadid/rpa1u7dd/)

I modified the example to replicate your conditions as closely as possible.

```
var data = '1","2","3","4';
var tArrx = new Array(data);
console.log('data '+data);
console.log('data.length '+data.length);
console.log('data[0] '+data[0]);
console.log('data[1] '+data[1]);
console.log('data[2] '+data[2]);
console.log('data[3] '+data[3]);
console.log(tArrx.length);
console.log(tArrx[0].length);
console.log(tArrx);
console.log(tArrx[0]);
$('.bHr').each(function(){
     curElm = $(this);
     var bTm = curElm.html();
     console.log(typeof bTm);
     console.log($.inArray(bTm, tArrx) !== -1);
     console.log($.inArray(bTm, tArrx[0]) !== -1);
     console.log($.inArray(bTm, data) !== -1);
});
```

Not having the beginning and ending quotes returned from your PHP request is causing the array assignment to return an array of length 1 populated with a string of length 13. This will cause `jQuery.inArray()` method to not find a match between 1 and the 13 char string. It can find 1 if you pass the string.  Fixing the missing beginning and ending qoutes is going to be your best solution.  Look at the console log from the updated working example.

```
 data 1","2","3","4
 data.length 13
 data[0] 1
 data[1] "
 data[2] ,
 data[3] "
 1
 13
 ["1","2","3","4"]
 1","2","3","4
 string
 false
 true
 true
 string
 false
 false
 false
```

Comment: 'data' is the response of a PHP file

Comment: @user1885099  I have the same question as EGP:  Can you show console log for tArrx?  

Console log for tArrx from my example looks like this:
[Array[4]]
0: Array[4]
   0: "1"
   1: "2"
   2: "3"
   3: "4"
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1

Comment: @user1885099  Did you query the length of data?  console.log(data.length);

Comment: @user1885099 Also query the length of tArrx and tArrx[0].  Look at the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have to cast the variables:

```
if ($.inArray(bTm.toString(), tArrx) !== -1)
```

Comment: If I define tArrx manually the function works fine, without having to add '.toString()'. The problem appears when I create the array using 'data'.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming the `toString` function is not solving the issue. I'll think somthing else.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo in this line:

```
    if ($.inArray(bTm, tArrx) !== -1){
```

shouldn't it be:

```
    if ($.inArray(Tbm, tArrx) !== -1){
```